# maximum number of qt signals to connect to one slot and maximum slots to connect to one signal

Tags: c++, qt

Does somebody know what's the maximum number of qt signals to connect to one slot, and what's the maximum slots to connect to one signal

Comment: It is unlimited.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO !

You can have as many signals you want connected to one slot and vice versa.

If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected, when the signal is emitted.

[Qt's Excellent Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) claims that **"on an i586-500, you can emit around 2,000,000 signals per second connected to one receiver, or around 1,200,000 per second connected to two receivers"**.

So, even if there is some sort of a theoretical limit on the number of slots that can be connected to a signal, this limit is surely beyond any practical relevance.